# Hardware implementation for integer data processing

Tags: image-processing, data-structures, hardware, fpga, signed

I am currently trying to implement a data path which processes an image data expressed in gray scale between unsigned integer 0 - 255. (Just for your information, my goal is to implement a Discrete Wavelet Transform in FPGA)

During the data processing, intermediate values will have negative numbers as well. As an example process, one of the calculation is

```
result = 48 - floor((66+39)/2)
```

The floor function is used to guarantee the integer data processing. For the above case, the result is -4, which is a number out of range between 0~255.

Having mentioned above case, I have a series of basic questions.

1. To deal with the negative intermediate numbers, do I need to represent all the data as 'equivalent unsigned number' in 2's complement for the hardware design? e.g. -4 d = 1111 1100 b.
2. If I represent the data as 2's complement for the signed numbers, will I need 9 bits opposed to 8 bits? Or, how many bits will I need to process the data properly? (With 8 bits, I cannot represent any number above 128 in 2's complement.)
3. How does the negative number division works if I use bit wise shifting? If I want to divide the result, -4, with 4, by shifting it to right by 2 bits, the result becomes 63 in decimal, 0011 1111 in binary, instead of -1. How can I resolve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: An [arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) could be used, and it would round downwards (as you specified) instead of towards zero (normal integer division).

Answer (score 1):

If you can choose to use VHDL, then you can use the [fixed point library](http://www.eda.org/fphdl/) to represent your numbers and choose your rounding mode, as well as allowing bit extensions etc.

In Verilog, well, I'd think twice.  I'm not a Verilogger, but the arithmetic rules for mixing signed and unsigned datatypes seem fraught with foot-shooting opportunities.

Another option to consider might be [MyHDL](http://www.myhdl.org/) as that gives you a very powerful verification environment and allows you to spit out VHDL or Verilog at the back end as you choose.